# Two tori $\mathbb C/L$ and $\mathbb C/L'$ are isomorph if $L=L'$

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

Let be two lattices $L$ and $L'$ given such that $L\subseteq L'$. Consider the canonical map from $\mathbb C/L$ to $\mathbb C/L'$.

Now I want to show that this map is an isomorphism (biholomorph) if and only if $L=L'$. The "if" part is obvious.

For the other direction I would like to write down the map which is as follows:

Let $L'=\mathbb Zv_1+\mathbb Zv_2$ then $L=\mathbb \alpha_1v_1\mathbb Z+\alpha_2v_2\mathbb Z$ for some $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in \mathbb Z$. Then the above map is given by

$$z+(\mathbb Zv_1+\mathbb Zv_2)\mapsto z+(\mathbb Z\alpha_1v_1+\mathbb Z\alpha_2v_2).$$

I start I hoped that this map is not injective if $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\neq 1$, but it seems that this is not the case...

So now I would like to check if this map is holomorph by using the definition. Somehow I am not able to get any restriction of $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$. Hopefully someone can help me a bit.

Comment: Your difficulties may be related to the fact that your displayed line appears to attempt to be a function from $\Bbb{C}/L'$ to $\Bbb{C}/L$. Instead you probably want to look at the mapping

$$z+(\mathbb Z\alpha_1v_1+\mathbb Z\alpha_2v_2)\mapsto z+(\mathbb Zv_1+\mathbb Zv_2).$$
What you wrote is not well defined. The cosets $z+L'$ and $z+v_1+L'$ are the same, but if $\alpha_1>1$ the corresponding cosets modulo $L$ are not.

Comment: You could simply apply basic facts about homomorphisms of groups (parallelogram laws and such) to the projection $p:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{C}/L'$. We have $\operatorname{ker}(p)=L'$, so the kernel of the induced projection $\tilde{p}:\Bbb{C}/L'\to\Bbb{C}/L$ is...

Comment: And my inner nitpicker wants to comment that the required integers $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ exist only when you choose the basis $v_1,v_2$ carefully. You need to invoke the stacked bases/aligned bases/whateveryouwanttocallit theorem to guarantee their existence.

Answer (score 1):

We denote $L'/L$ as the set of cosets of $L'$ under $L$ (looked at as abelian groups). Clearly $|L'/L|=1$ if and only if $L'=L$. We note that, denoting the map $f:\mathbb{C}/L\to \mathbb{C}/L'$, we have that $L'/L\subseteq \mathbb{C}/L$, and we have that $f(L'/L)=[L']$, a single element. Thus for $f$ to be an isomorphisms, we must have that $L'/L$ consists of a single element, so that by the above reasoning, $L'=L$ as desired.